# Routing table different than expected

Tags: routing, ping

I'm using virtual machines in virtualbox. These virtual machines are linux ubuntu.
One machine has 4 interfaces (eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3) and to each interface I assign an IP address. But when I look at the routing table of this machine then this should contain the directly connected networks (i.e. destinations are the assigned IP-addresses, except the last number is 0), but sometimes this is not the case, and this machine can ping other machines than neighbours, even if I have not added a static route. What could be the cause?

For example:

I add 192.160.7.1/16 to eth2

192.168.5.1/16 to eth0

192.168.40.1/21 to eth1

192.168.128.1/1 to eth3

But the routing table has as destination entries

192.160.0.0 (this should be 192.160.7.0)

192.168.0.0 (this should be 192.168.5.1)

192.168.40.0

192.168.128.0

Sorry if I'm wrong, I'm new with this :)

Comment: Give us concrete information. Tell us the IP it can reach. Show us the routing table.

Comment: Why do you think 192.168.0.0 should be 192.168.5.1? Do you understand what 192.168.5.1 / **16** means? You're getting exactly what you should expect, so the question is why you expect something different.

Comment: No sorry, I'm new with this :)

Comment: Basically, you just have to learn how Ethernet and IP work, or get someone else to work out your IP assignments. (And if you really thought the route should be to 192.168.5.1, wouldn't that mean the machine could only reach iitself?)

Answer (score 2):

You don't just assign Ethernet interfaces IP addresses. You assign them IP addresses on a network. And they then get a route to the other IP addresses on that network. LANs wouldn't work without special configuration were this not the case.

The `/16` in "192.168.5.1/16" means there are 16-bits in the network portion of the address. This means there are 16 bits in the host portion. So the route to every other address in the local network will cover 192.168.0.0 through 192.168.255.255. If this isn't what you want, don't use a /16 netmask.

Comment: It looks like you want to use /24 instead of /16.